# my coin transferred on 17 Dec and confirmed on 31 Dec still showing unspent on 5 Jan

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, listunspent

I have done a couple of transaction in Blockchain but have never experienced such problem. I transfered coins from my wallet to another account by choosing custom fee option on 17 Dec which got confirmed on 31 Dec and showing unspent there till 5 Jan now. 
https://blockchain.info/tx/592d3405f60e87c55afa72b989354c7f773def2bca848bb0f15d3039c4d6b91e

I hope my coins are safe and will get it soon?
please help
Manoj

Comment: Whatt do you mean as unspent? TX seems fine

Answer (score 3):

That transaction is valid and confirmed.

"Unspent" in the right-hand column means that the *outputs* have not been spent.  The funds are still sitting in the 1965... and 144f... addresses and have not been moved out of those addresses.

If one or both of those addresses belong to you (i.e. you generated them with your own wallet and have the private key(s)), then you can spend those funds any time you like.

If they belong to someone else (e.g. a merchant from whom you are trying to buy something, an exchange where you are trying to make a deposit to your account, etc.) then that person has the funds.  If they haven't acknowledged the funds (delivered your order, credited your account, etc) then that is something you have to take up with them directly.  But the Bitcoin protocol has done its job at this point.

Comment: hi, I have transfer to my account with other exchange so if they have not acknowledge the fund, Can I get that unspent coins back to my blockchain wallet? or else how can I ask them to acknowledge if they have not done yet?

Comment: @ManojMishra: No, you can't get the coins back.  The exchange has complete control over them now.  You can keep contacting them, or try to escalate to higher management, or call a lawyer and look into your legal options.  But from a technical point of view, there is nothing you can do, and nothing further we here can help you with.